# While loop and toggling table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a table with `<theader>`. Underneath each header, my PHP generates a `<tbody>` My goal is to toggle the `<tbody>` underneath each of these headers once the user clicks on the Table Header. Each `<theader>` has a unique id and so does the `<tbody>` that corresponds to it. So for example the header is #GenEdCategory1 and clicking on it will toggle #GenEdCourses1. and so on for #GenEdCategory2 and #GenEdCourses2 ...

I used these selectors for jQuery to do the toggling.

When I hardcode it, it works fine! Clicking on #GenEdCategory1 will toggle the #GenEdCourses1. But I want to make it dynamic based on the number of headers that have been fetched, I can't toggly anything!

I do this using a while loop but when I code it, it stops working. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Cheers :)

```
var numberCategory = $('[id^=GenEdCategory]').length; //calculates number of GenEdCategories
            var idCntr = 1;                                       //GenEdCategory ctr
            var cool = "#GenEdCategory" + idCntr;   //click on this to toggle
            var cool2 = "#GenEdCourses" + idCntr;   //I want to toggle this

          while (idCntr < numberCategory) {
              $(document).on("click", cool, function(){
                $(cool2).toggle();
             });
              idCntr = idCntr + 1;
              cool = "#GenEdCategory" + idCntr;
              cool2 = "#GenEdCourses" + idCntr;
            };
          };
        };
```

Here's the HTML Snippet of the table I'm working with:
[image]

Comment: can you add the html too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's DOM traversal function to do it in a single function, not a loop, and there's no need to give them IDs.

```
$("thead").click(function() {
    $(this).next("tbody").toggle();
});
```

BTW, `<theader>` should be `<thead>`.